# How can I make it better this json checker function? PYTHON

Tags: python, json, function, for-loop

I am a beginner pythonist.
I wish someone would take a look at my function and give me feedback on it.
I have the feeling that exists an optimal and easier way to check the installment value.
But I am not able to find it myself.

***CASE:
Check-in JSON if the installment values ​​are> 100.
Provide a message when installments <100.***

case

```
my_json = [
   {
        "id": "A1",
        "price": 43900,
        "products": [
            {
                "product": "cash",
                "installment": 43900
            },
            {
                "product": "loan",
                "installment": 469.57
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "A2",
        "price": 99900.00,
        "products": [
             {
                "product": "cash",
                "installment": 99900.00
            },
            {
                "product": "loan",
                "installment": 1053.49
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "A3",
        "price": 56900,
        "products": [
            {
                "product": "cash",
                "installment": 56900
            },
            {
                "product": "lease",
                "installment": 285.05
            },
            {
                "product": "loan",
                "installment": 65.12
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

My function that checks the value of an installment

```
def instalments_check():
    for obj in my_json:
        for key, value in obj.items():
            if key == "products":
                for k in value:
                    for key1,value1 in k.items():
                        if key1 == "installment":
                            if value1 >= 100:
                                print("installment is correct")
                            if value1 <= 100:
                                print("installment is incorrect in {}".format(obj))

instalments_check()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the keys of a dictionary directly, instead of iterating over them. Something like this would be easier to follow.

```py
def installments_check():
    for obj in my_json:
        for product in obj['products']:
            if product['installment'] >= 100:
                print("installment is correct")
            else:
                print("installment is incorrect in {}".format(obj))
```

Comment: Thanks for this tip. Next time I’ll use your path.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is basically pretty good but there is one error if the value is 100 then it gives you both messages. To fix this just use elif instead of the second if statement.